# Magento Please use the 2fa provider-specific endpoints to obtain a token error REST API on Admin token

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4

Magento Rest API to fetch admin token credentials to use tokens for other REST APIs as Authorization Bearer.

From Magento 2.4+, the Two Factor Authentication Module is available for security reasons.

generate Admin Token by REST API and you will face an error in a response like below, You have authenticated Google 2FA for security reasons.

```
{
    "message": "Please use the 2fa provider-specific endpoints to obtain a token.",
    "parameters": {
        "active_providers": [
            "google"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate an admin access token in an alternative way,

**Action:** POST

**URL:** <BASE_URL>/rest/V1/tfa/provider/google/authenticate (Replace your actual URL with BASE_URL)

**Body:**

```
  {
        "username":"rakesh", 
        "password":"MyPassword", 
        "otp":"<SIX_DIGIT_OTP_CODE_FROM_GOOGLE_AUTHENICATOR_APP>"
  }
```

In the Payload, You need to pass your admin username/password with the respective field.

- username Your Magento Admin user
- password Your Magento Admin password
- otp value will be a six-digit code from the Google Authenticator
  Mobile Apps.

Response Example:

```
eyJraWQiOiIxIiwiYWxnIjoiSFMyNTYifQ.eyJ1aWQiOjU1LCJ1dHlwaWQiOjIsImlhdCI6MTY5Mjc0NzQzNywiZXhwIjoxNjkyNzUxMDM3fQ.jJXT9DAjRS4y4Q2j4xZt16JYgs7lClO94uNu8Calgfw
```

The Response comes from the TFA provider REST API will be used to other APIs with Header.

Authorization Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN> While Replace ACCESS_TOKEN from the response string value.